# QField GPS lost when screen is off

Tags: qfield

I'm using QField on Android 9 and when I lock screen it loses the GPS and stops tracking...
I went to parameter and battery optimisation and switched QField to *not optimised*, but it still happens...
Does anyone know how to keep it from stopping tracking?

Answer (score 2):

When QField is running in the background or the screen is turned off, the GNSS receiver stops sending information to QField.
To prevent this, the screen remains on as long as QField is running in the foreground.

To prevent high battery usage, the brightness is heavily dimmed. But this is only since the current beta release: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v2.0.2

Comment: OK, i've seen this yesterday, and seen that running in background was added to futur features, guess i'll wait.